# AES encryption in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

I'm trying to convert a module writing in Python to Perl 6, I find there is no [AES](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/examples.html) method in Perl 6:

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
import base64

def aes(text, key):
    pad = 16 - len(text) % 16
    text = text + bytearray([pad] * pad)
    encryptor = AES.new(key, 2, b"0102030405060708")
    ciphertext = encryptor.encrypt(text)
    return base64.b64encode(ciphertext)
```

Is there any module writing in Perl 6 that implemented **AES** method?

Comment: I searched for aes on modules.perl6.org. I see a `Text::Caesar`. Is that related? Are you opposed to using the Python module you mention or some other existing non P6 module?

Comment: It's about Encrypt, maybe using `Inline::Python` instead.

Comment: Or use a P5 module. (Or the P6 OpenSSL as per jnthn's answer?) Lots of options...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that the `OpenSSL` module provides access to various AES ciphers. It depends on the openssl library being available (although on Windows I believe it downloads the DLL as part of the module installation process).

With that installed (`zef install OpenSSL`), one can:

```
use OpenSSL::CryptTools;
```

And then use `encrypt`/`decrypt`:

```
# Fake IV and key
my $iv = ('0' x 16).encode;
my $key = ('xy' x 16).encode;

# Encrypt.
my $ciphertext = encrypt("asdf".encode, :aes256, :$iv, :$key);
say $ciphertext;

# Decrypt.
say decrypt($ciphertext, :aes256, :$iv, :$key).decode;
```

See [these tests](https://github.com/sergot/openssl/blob/edf86b6dbc7ba6dfc44cdc7e4dd853fc6ca189cb/t/04-crypt.t) for more examples.

Comment: thanks @Jonathan Worthington, it's the thing i looked for,  change `$iv` to *0102030405060708*, it works well. HAPPY NEW YEAR!